# What to do with webpack-dev-server when deploying for production?

Tags: node.js, deployment, gcloud, webpack-3

I did a simple and static web-app following [Material-Design-Components Get started guide](https://material.io/components/web/docs/getting-started/), but deployment is not covered there. 
The project works locally and in Goggle Cloud Shell without any issue and now I want to deploy and publish the web.

What should I do with `webpack-dev-server` if I want to deploy correctly? Uninstall it? Or replace it with another dependency? Could someone point me in the right direction?

As suggested in the guide above, I am using webpack3 and webpack-dev-server2.

Thanks

Comment: Using `webpack-dev-server` doesn't factor in to your deployment at all - most of the time, you should just do a `webpack` build and deploy the static files that it generates.

Comment: I agree with @JoeClay. I don't see why it should affect the deployment. Have a look in this [community example](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-nodejs-webpack#deploying-the-app), where they only add the app.yaml file, and in [Google official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app) which explains and guides through the deployment process.